# How to get Ant to preserve directory structure inside the JAR?

Tags: ant, jar

I have tried the advice from lots of other threads here. They often instruct me to set file set and then include the directories that I want. It either results in the wrong directories or the right directories, but not possible to execute the JAR. I need to preserve the directory structure inside the JAR, so the Java application can find the resources. As it is now, all the right directories are included in the JAR file, but it is not possible to execute it. I get this error message:

"no main attribute in memory.jar"

It can't find the classes to execute. I think it is because they now are in the bin directory, but Java is looking for them in the base directory. How do I change my ANT script, to make this work?

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\memory.jar" >
        <fileset dir=".">

        </fileset>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="memory.Memory" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. The jar command works properly. You can verify using 7Zip or other util.

Comment: Yes, the JAR command works, but there are 2 problems. All the directories in the project are included in my JAR now. I only want to include memory,meta-inf
and settingsfolder. 

The second problem is that the generated JAR can not be executed and the error message

"no main attribute in memory.jar"
 
is generated. The main class to be executed is
memory.Memory, which is in this directory: memory\memory\Memory.class. Maybe Java is looking for the main class in the root directory? Should I set it to look for the main class in the memory\memory directory?